# problem with a Spring applicaiton finding class org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet (IDE is Eclipse)

Tags: jakarta-ee

I am trying to create a Spring Web application,  and I am having trouble 
calling a servlet from the Spring library. I have the servlet defined in the XML 
file but at run time it can't find it,  I probably am having an issue with the 
class path somehow. Here is the message I am getting at runtime

Servlet    org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet             is not 
available

the above mentioned servelet is a class but I can't seem to get the xml file 
to point to where its at in my project.

Any ideas?

Comment: Do you have org.springframework.web.servlet-3.0.3.RELEASE.jar in your WEB-INF/lib/ folder ?

Comment: If you are deploying your WAR file in an EAR file of your own construction, you need to select the spring jar file in the J2EE Module Dependencies tab in your project's properties.

Answer (score 0):

Some ideas:

- Double check that the required Spring jars are declared as "Web App Libraries" (
  and get deployed under WEB-INF/lib)
- Check your server logs for the real cause (and post the full stack trace if necessary).